# Название запирающего механизма

Tags: грамотная-речь, названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется затворяющая передвижка? Затвор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам механизм, показанный на фотографии, является запорным устройством и называется [дверная врезная **защёлка**](https://legkovmeste.ru/stroitelstvo-i-remont/dveri/zashchelka-dvernaya-mezhkomnatnaya.html). Она устанавливается в торец дверного полотна; может быть самостоятельным устройством или частью замка.
Тот элемент, который выступает из двери, называется **язычок** (если я "правильно" вижу, то он металлический, скошенный).

Устройства такого типа используются на дверях, которые монтируются в жилых помещениях. Как правило, их устанавливают в дверных проемах, ведущих в спальни, гостиные или кухонные помещения. Защёлки предотвращают открытие дверного полотна.